# QFileSystemWatcher::addPath recursively

Tags: c++, qt, directory, subdirectory, qfilesystemwatcher

Hi all I want to use `QFileSystemWatcher` to watch changes of a given directory and its subdirectory recursively, but `void QFileSystemWatcher::addPath ( const QString & path )` didn't let me do it so is there any idea to do it easily or I should implement it by my self (extract all directories and subdirectories and files under to added with `void QFileSystemWatcher::addPaths ( const QStringList & paths )`)?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/5.0/qfilesystemwatcher.html#details) of class `QFileSystemWatcher` doesn't state that recursive watching is part of its contract. So I think a solution might be, as you hinted, to walk the directory tree yourself, gather all sub-directories and their files in a string list and use

```
void QFileSystemWatcher::addPaths ( const QStringList & paths )
```

Also, I think it might be useful for you to mention which version of qt you are working with, because according to this [thread](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/merge_requests/2611),  `QFileSystemWatcher` is being deprecated and a new api is supposed to replace it.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response, am using QtSdk-v1_2_1(QT 4.8.1), `Old prototype: void QFileSystemWatcher::addPath ( const QString & path )` is provided,  so I think I will proceed it by my self,thank you one more time .

Comment: This is an [example](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/qt/0596000642/working-with-files-and-directories/prowqt2-chp-11-sect-2) illustrating how to walk a directory using **QDir**. You can easily adapt it to suit your needs.

Comment: One thing to watch out for if you're adding a subtree this way... According to the QFileSystemWatcher documentation: "Some system limits the number of open file descriptors to 256 by default." If I understand correctly, this means that if there are more than 256 subdirectories, this approach will fail on some systems.